# Using Ajax in laravel and giving me unknown status. Why?

Tags: ajax, laravel

In my application i am using Ajax request but it is giving me jquery-3.3.1.js:9600 POST http://localhost:8000/get_types_ajax

> gettin 419 (unknown status)

My javascript is:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

    var ckbox = $("input[name='particulars']");
    var chkId = '';
    $("input[name='particulars']").on('change', function() {

      if (ckbox.is(':checked')) {
          values = [];
          names = [];
          $("input[name='particulars']:checked").each ( function() {
              amount = $(this).val().split(",");
              console.log("amount",amount);
              values.push(amount[0]);
              names.push(amount[1]);
          });//checked
         total_value = 0;

         values.forEach(function(value) {
            value = Number(value);
            total_value = total_value + value;
            document.getElementById('total').innerHTML = total_value;
        });//foreach
     }//if     
    else {
        total_value = 0;
        document.getElementById('total').innerHTML = total_value;
    }

    $.ajax({    url:"{{url('/get_types_ajax')}}",
                type: 'POST',
                data: {message:names},
                success: function (data) 
                { 
                  console.log(data);
                } 
                }); 
        });//onchange
 });//ready
```

my web.php is :

```
 Route::post('/get_types_ajax', 'DevkrutyaController@get_types');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 419 error you are getting is due to the missing CSRF token in your ajax request. To pass a csrf token you can use ajax setup method of jquery

```
 $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': '{{ csrf_token() }}'
        }
    });
$.ajax({
            url:"{{url('/get_types_ajax')}}",
            type: 'POST',
            data: {message:names},
            success: function (data) 
            { 
              console.log(data);
            } 
            }); 
    });//onchange

});//ready
```

For more information https://laravel.com/docs/master/csrf#csrf-x-csrf-token

Answer (score 1):

i see.You don't pass `CSRF_TOKEN`  WITH Post Request 
if your are using post method then u must pass `CSRF_TOKEN` with that other wise you can ignore(skip) some Url in VerifyCSRF token middleware

```
 protected $except = [
        'stripe/*',
 ];
```

> other wise add this line in your js file it will automatically send
>   csrf token

```
 $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        }
    });
```

for more detail read this [article](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/csrf)

Answer (score 1):

Laravel uses CSRF token to protect your application from cross-site request forgery (CSRF) attacks. You will need to pass the CSRF token in your ajax.

**In header**

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}" />
```

**In script**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
});
</script>
```

Comment: Yes i have now added the CSRF-TOKEN but still getting the same error